# Need assistance regarding common issue of view jumping 20px up

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Lot of peoples asked question regarding view jumping 20px up but still its not clearly understand why it happens, many people says to set `CGRect` to adjust this issue but its not a proper solution.

This is my case, what I did is:

In my ViewController.xib file I drag n dropped another `UIView` and in ViewComreoller.h file I created its `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *settingsView;`

In ViewController.m file

```
- (IBAction)settings:(id)sender {

    [UIView transitionFromView:[self view] toView:[self settingsView] duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
}

- (IBAction)back:(id)sender {

    [UIView transitionFromView:[self settingsView] toView:[self view] duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
}
```

and thats all.

When `settingsView` appear it jumped 20px up.

Both views are same width and hight, and all I did `transitionFromView:`, no custom code but still its jumping up, why?

Please help regarding this issue and clear my concepts why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

check whether your status bar is still there?. The 20px might be the issue with the status bar at the top.

There are chances like in xib you have enabled status bar and in project you ma not be showing the status bar. You can completely aviod statusbar by editing the info.plist. Add a row with Key "Status bar is initially hidden" to YES.